# How do applications know character encoding?

Tags: unicode, encoding, cat

Lets say I have two files as below :

```
$ ll
total 8
-rw-rw-r--. 1 matias matias 6 Nov 27 20:25 ascii.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 matias matias 8 Nov 28 21:57 unicode.txt
```

Both contain a single line of text, but there is an extra character in the second file as shown here ( Greek letter Sigma ) :

```
$ cat ascii.txt
   matias
$ cat unicode.txt
   matiasΣ
```

If I pass them through **file** command this is the output :

```
$ file *
  ascii.txt:   ASCII text, with no line terminators
  unicode.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators
```

Which seems ok. Now If I make an **hexdump** of the file I get this :

```
 $ hexdump -C ascii.txt
   00000000  6d 61 74 69 61 73                     |matias|
   00000006

 $ hexdump -C unicode.txt
   00000000  6d 61 74 69 61 73 ce a3               |matias..|
   00000008
```

So, my question is, how does an application as **cat** know that the last two bytes are actually a **single Unicode character**. If I print the last two bytes individually I get:

```
 $ printf '%d' '0xce'
   206
 $ printf '%d' '0xa3'
   163
```

Which in extended ASCII are :

```
 $ py3 -c 'print(chr(206))'
   Î
 $ py3 -c 'print(chr(163))'
   £
```

Is my logic flawed? What Am I missing here?

Comment: Your terminal is apparently configured to support UTF-8, not Latin-1 ("extended ASCII"). I wouldn't be surprised if `cat` doesn't care about that at all, it's probably only handled in display by your terminal emulator (in contrast to tools like `wc`, which you can tell to count bytes or multi-byte characters).

Comment: In more general terms: I assume that tools will look at your locale env vars (`LC*`) if they need to know the character encoding of text IO. Note that ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so treating a plain-ASCII text file as UTF-8 will always work.

Comment: But when cat reads byte to byte the file in disk. why does it not print "matias" followed by the two symbols representing decimal 206 and 163 instead of a single sigma character? what happens If I actually want to put the character represented by byte 206 for instance?

Comment: The `cat` tool sends the bytes 206 and 163 to the terminal, which expects UTF-8 text. Thus the terminal displays the two bytes as a single character, because that's how UTF-8 works. If some command sends the byte 206 in isolation, the terminal will display �, because that's an invalid byte sequence in UTF-8.

Comment: When you do `print(chr(206))`, you get the character with Unicode codepoint 206. Python has means to detect your terminal encoding and will send the bytes 195 and 142, because that's the UTF-8 representation of the character "Î". Does it make sense?

Comment: @lenz Ok. thanks so much for your answer. If you put post it Ill highlight it as correct. It was clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-line tools work with bytes – they receive bytes and send bytes.
The notion of a character – be it represented by a single or multiple bytes – is a task-specific interpretation of the raw bytes.
When you call `cat` on a UTF-8 file, I assume it just forwards the bytes it reads without caring about characters.

But your terminal, which has to display the output of `cat`, *does* take care to interpret the bytes as characters and show a single character for the byte sequence 206, 163.
From its configuration (`locale` env vars etc.), your terminal apparently assumes that text IO happens with UTF-8.
If this assumption is violated (eg. if a command sends the byte 206 in isolation, which is invalid UTF-8), you will see � symbols or other text garbage.
Since UTF-8 was designed to be backwards-compatible to ASCII, ASCII text files can be treated just like UTF-8 files (the *are* UTF-8).

While `cat` probably doesn't care about characters, many other commands do, eg. the `wc -m` command to count characters (not bytes!) in a text file.
Such commands all need to know how UTF-8 (or whatever your terminal encoding is) maps bytes to characters and vice versa.
For example, when you `print(chr(206))` in Python, then it sends the bytes 195, 142 to STDOUT because:
(a) it has figured out your terminal expects UTF-8 and (b) the character "Î" (to which Unicode codepoint 206 corresponds) is represented with these two bytes in UTF-8.
Finally, the terminal displays "Î", because it decodes the two bytes to the corresponding character.

Answer (score 0):

> How do applications know character encoding?

Either:

1. (They guess—perhaps with heuristics. This isn't "knowing".)
2. They tell you exactly which one to use (via documentation, standard, convention, etc). (This isn't really "knowing" either.)
3. They allow you to tell them which one you are using.

*It's your file; You have to know.*